# Apache2: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /dir/ on this server

Tags: apache2

I can access `localhost` but not the sub directories `index.html`

My `default conf` looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/*/>
    Allow from None
    Order allow,deny
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Even after allowing `read/edit/write` access to the directory, its showing Forbidden error. Tried all possible ways out in forums, didnt worked. Anyone has a solution.

Between above I tried something for `sub directory` access:

```
<Directory /var/www/*/>
    Allow from None
    Order allow,deny
</Directory>
```

Please suggest me possible solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let's make the vhost clear:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then make sure you set the right permission like this:

```
sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www
```

Comment: I did so. Still the same. Restarted apache as well. Should I try to modify in apache.conf instead?

Comment: Here is the thing. I tried to change root directory, to my home folder index and its still pointing to /var/www. Gotta find right conf file.

Comment: Just great. Only neede to add the www-data user. now all my local network user can use the content

Comment: I must say this is really frustrating

Answer (score 3):

This works for me, very well:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Checkout this tutorial: https://www.tecmint.com/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server-error/