# 403 Forbidden on Apache 2.4

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I've read the answer at [Apache2: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /dir/ on this server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292968/apache2-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-dir-on-this-server) as well as all of the related questions and none of the solutions seem to work.

I'm trying to set up Apache with SSL but am getting a 403 Forbidden error when I go to `https://[::1]/` or `https://localhost/`.

My only "sites-enabled" are `localssl` and this is `localssl.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        ####Configuration for SSL #####
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
        #### End of SSL Configuration ####

        DocumentRoot /data
        <Directory /data>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

Permissions for `/data` are set to `755` for `root:www-data` recursively.

In my `apache2.conf` file:

```
#<Directory /var/www/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>

<Directory /data/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I've also tried omitting the section in `apache2.conf` and it did not make a difference.

What else do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: I know you set permission recursively for /data but did you verify the permission for the html file, if there is one? use `ls -l /data/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by adding `Indexes` into the Options directive:

In the `Directory` "node" inside `localssl.conf`:

```
    <Directory /data>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check port number in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and /etc/apache2/ports.conf . It should be the same.