# Forbidden You don't have permission to access /UI on this server

Tags: apache2

i dont know what is wrong.
i tried almost everything to fix the issue

my apache2.conf:
http://pastebin.com/qF16MCYd

error in browser
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /UI on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

i hope you guys can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

in your appache conf file, you do not declare access to /UI, you need to add a Vblock such as :

```
<Directory "/UI">
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: i added it and restarted apache2, but it doesnt work.
still the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/292968/apache2-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-dir-on-this-server?rq=1