# Can't open folder after giving it www-data group, how do I become owner?

Tags: permissions, apache2, localhost, ownership, groups

I was running localhost (Apache 2.4.6) but only the `index.php` was openable in the web browser. The subdirectories  were returning 403 Forbidden error.

Now, I added the permissions according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/292971/272801). For reference, these were the permissions:

```
sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www
```

Accordingly, the folder in which I placed all the content of the website became owned by `www-data` group. And although I've added myself to the group, I cannot open the folder!

(But the subdirectories have become accessible from the web browser.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First are you sure your user is added to www-data group? The proper way to add your user to this group is:

```
sudo adduser yourusername www-data
```

Then do:

```
sudo chown yourusername:www-data -R /var/www
```

After that, you should change permissions to 755, it is not recommend changing permissions to 777 for security reasons

```
sudo chmod 0755 -R /var/www  
sudo chmod g+s -R /var/www
```

Comment: Oh it worked! I just didn't do the last step (change permissions to 755). By the way, my directory was not /var/www. Thanks!